# En un for, cuando se le resta en la actualización y en la condición, ¿por qué empieza a leer al revés el array?

Tags: javascript

Estaba mirando los array en javascript y no entiendo bien: cuando se le resta en la actualización y en la condición, ¿por qué empieza a leer al revés el array?

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3];
 
for (let i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log(nums[i]);
}
 
console.log('Time is up!');
```

Lo que entiendo del código:
`i = 2`, y si `i` es mayor igual a 0 se le resta 1, con lo cual del 2 al 0 hay 3 números por así decirlo y eso saca los 3 que hay. Pero ¿no es casi lo mismo que poner el `.length`? Y sigo sin entender por qué así se invierte la lectura del array y empieza por el 3.

Comment: `length` te devuelve la cantidad de elementos del Array. Dado que los Arrays inician su índice en 0 y no en 1, has de restar una unidad a `length` para obtener el índice del último elemento del Array. Saludos

Comment: El i-- se ejecuta una vez que se hace lo que este dentro del ciclo, y después se realiza la comparación (Sin contar la primera ejecución que esa verifica primero y no resta a menos que se haga una vez el ciclo).

Comment: Si alguna respuesta te fue de utilidad solucionando tu caso, recuerda marcarla como aceptada, de este modo colaboras con la buena salud del sitio (% de respuestas resueltas). Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Básicamente, los ciclos `for` reciben 3 argumentos, separados por punto y coma (`;`):

1. Ejecutar sentencia al iniciar, generalmente es para definir variables
2. Establecer una condición que se va a evaluar en cada iteración y finalizar el ciclo cuando el resultado sea falso
3. Ejecutar sentencia después de cada iteración

Ten en cuenta que las sentencias a ejecutar pueden ser variadas, pero el uso general que se les da es crear variables al inicio y modificarlas después de cada iteración.

En tu ejemplo, se recorre el arreglo en orden inverso:

1. Comienzas con la cantidad de elementos del arreglo (3) menos uno, para acceder al último elemento, que tiene 2 como índice, porque los índices comienzan en cero
2. Se ejecuta mientras la variable `i` sea mayor o igual que cero, que es el primer elemento del arreglo
3. Después de cada iteración, se resta uno para poder acceder al elemento anterior

```js
const nums = [
    1, // Posición cero
    2, // Posición 1
    3  // Posición 2
];
 
for (
    let i = nums.length - 1;  // Definir variable al iniciar
    i >= 0;                   // Condición para seguir ejecutando
    i--                       // Qué hacer después de cada iteración
) {
  // Se ejecutan las instrucciones especificadas
  console.log(nums[i]);
  // Después, se realiza la operación del tercer argumento
}
 
console.log('Time is up!');
```

Si inviertes el orden de los elementos del arreglo, puedes ejecutar el ciclo comenzando en cero y sumando hasta que se encuentre el último elemento del arreglo:

```js
const nums = [
    3, // Posición cero
    2, // Posición 1
    1  // Posición 2
];
 
for (
    let i = 0;        // Comenzar en cero
    i < nums.length;  // Mientras i sea menor que la cantidad de elementos
    i++               // Incrementar i
) {
  // Se ejecutan las instrucciones especificadas
  console.log(nums[i]);
  // Después, se realiza la operación del tercer "parámetro"
}
 
console.log('Time is up!');
```

Answer (score 1):

yo lo haria asi:

```
const nums = [1, 2, 3];
 
for (let i = 0; i <nums.length; i++) {
  console.log(nums[i]);
}
 
console.log('Time is up!');
```

porque el primer valor del array es 0 y tu esta comenzando con el ultimo por esto te esta poniendo los numeros al reves

Answer (score 1):

> ¿por qué empieza a leer al revés el array?

Respuesta corta, porque estás definiendo el inicio como el último elemento.

Explicación:

```
const nums = [1, 2, 3];
 
for (let i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  // Primera parte del FOR.
  // let i = nums.length - 1
  // inicialización de la variable i = longitud del arreglo -1
  // considerando que los arreglos inician en la posición 0.
  // Hay 3 elementos, ergo 3 - 1 = 2 y esto está bien porque:
  // hay elemento en posición 0, posición 1 y posición 2.

  // Segunda parte del FOR
  // i >= 0
  // Es la condición para que el loop se mantenga.
  // Estás diciendo que la variable "i" sea mayor o igual a 0.

  // Tercera parte del FOR:
  // i--
  // Estás restando el valor de 1, considerando que la primera pasada inició en 2:
  // la segunda pasada obtendrá el valor en la posición 1.
  // Finalmente para la tercera pasada obtendrá el valor en la posición 0.
  console.log(nums[i]);
}
 
console.log('Time is up!');
```